# How to get detail information when handling Fetch API exception?

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch

Catching exception while using Fetch API, the browser will log this to console:

```
POST https://xxx.xx net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

In the catch branch, I can catch the error thrown by fetch API and it looks like this:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

With this exception, I can't really figure out what's happening in client side.

How can I get this message (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID) in the code?

e.g.

try this snippet in the console:

```js
function pureRequest(url, config) {
  if (config.body && typeof config.body === 'object') {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(config.body);
  }
  return window.fetch(url, config).then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      return response.json().then(function (r) {
        return Promise.reject(r);
      });
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

pureRequest('https://www.google.com', {})
```

It will log a CORS Error in the console, but all you can get from the catch branch is `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. Can I get the infomation in the Error log in console?

Comment: @stark I have edited. please check.

Comment: If I am doing from same origin, for example `google.com` in this case, I get `VM102:14 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, could you elaborate a bit more? From what you have pasted seems you are missing necessary certs to access the site

Comment: @stark I was trying to collect users' error infomation. From what I collected, I found out nearly 10% of users will report 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'. But this log couldn't help me getting infomation for what actual problem my users are facing. So I need more information, and I think the log that browser put into console is useful.